# Invalid bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I have a document were I use the LaTeX-Assistant from citavi. That produces a `bib` file and can get converted with `bibtex`.
My problem is to know how to change the style for the bibliography from `unsrt` to `chem-angew` or similar.

```
\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, parskip, 12pt, toc=bibnumbered, captions=tableheading,captions=nooneline, BCOR5mm,  headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
**\usepackage[english]{babel} %tried also [ngerman, english]**
\usepackage[square, comma, numbers, sort, sort&compress, super]{natbib} %**sort&compress does not work**
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} %here, should be the other style, solved with {angew}

\begin{document}
...
complex interactions in such systems **\cite{Groschel.2015} with \cite{Groschel.2015} is "A. H. Gröschel, A. H. E. Müller, Nanoscale 2015, 7, 11841." did not work.**
...
 
\bibliography{Latex_phD_Literature} %**How can I change it from Bibliography=references**

\end{document}
```

Comment: `chem-angew` is a `biblatex` bibliography style and not supposed to be used in combination with `natbib`/`bibtex`. If you're not willing to switch to `biblatex`, you probably want to try the `angew` bibliography style.

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot I was just looking for this style what worked in the permeable. 

Now another problem appears which I can not solve my own.  New codes in the head comment included. 

As I have ref with ä etc. I need to include a language package but even if I include [ngerman,englisch]{babel} 
"LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook
(hooks) 'file/after/translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl'"

 I can not use the package also the usepages with natbib (sort¬compress and general sort) get kind of ignored.